# creating an inputbox with different buttons

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbs code and i would like to change the way an `InputBox` is shown.

I want to create an `InputBox` that instead of "OK" and "Cancel" buttons will show different button labels

Is it possible in vbs?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible with the built-in [`InputBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function. You need to create a [custom dialog](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_userinput.php#InternetExplorer) for that:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "about:blank"
ie.Document.title = "Title"
ie.ToolBar        = False
ie.Resizable      = False
ie.StatusBar      = False
ie.Width          = 320
ie.Height         = 180

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

ie.Document.body.innerHTML = _
  "<p><input type='text' size='20' id='UserInput'></p>" & vbNewLine & _
  "<p><input type='hidden' id='OK' name='OK' value='0'>" & _
  "<input type='submit' value='Foo' onClick='VBScript:OK.value=1'></p>"
ie.Document.body.style.overflow = "auto"

ie.Visible = True
ie.Document.all.UserInput.focus

On Error Resume Next
Do While ie.Document.all.OK.value = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
On Error Goto 0
```

Use stylesheets for customizing the appearance of the dialog:

```
Set style = ie.Document.CreateStyleSheet
style.AddRule "*", "margin:0; padding:0; border:0;"
style.AddRule "body", "font-family:serif; font-size:12px; text-align:center;"
style.AddRule ".button", "border:2px outset; width:70px;"
...
```